# HTML code compatibility in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

The below html code displays a basic sign up/login form for the user, I want to use it within a page that is built using the jquery mobile library.

At the moment its not working, I'm new to jquery mobile and not sure if I'm breaking a fundamental law and cannot simply drop this into the page and expect it to work.

I'm thinking I may need to change the code for the buttons to make them work correctly?

I have researched this, but cannot find a 100% answer to the question I'm asking.

```
<script type="text/template" id="login-template">
  <header id="header"></header>
  <div class="login">
    <form class="login-form">
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="login-username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" id="login-password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button>Log In</button>
    </form>

    <form class="signup-form">
      <h2>Sign Up</h2>
      <div class="error" style="display:none"></div>
      <input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" placeholder="Create a Password" />
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: HTML code not supposed to be put inside `script` tag

Comment: @AtanuCSE: HTML5 allows this to insert _data_ into a document – the `type` must just not be one that gets it interpreted as scripting language. (Also it should be a valid MIME type.)

Comment: Where have you placed that code? in head, body...?

Comment: Between the body tags

Answer (score -2):

Why is your HTML content within the `<script></script>` tags? I'm not familiar with the jQuery Mobile module, however, basic HTML would say this wouldn't work anyway.

Try removing said tags to see if it works then. I'm not actually sure what you're trying to achieve, so, I can't really contribute a great deal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow-  This answer is more of a question than an answer, so that is why it is being downvoted.  Try giving this kind of response in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: At the time of posting this "answer", I was unable to post comments. Apologies.